# How to use glue inside of lapply

Tags: sql, r, r-glue

I'm trying to use the function `glue_sql` inside of `lapply`, but I'm running into a problem.

I have a long list of IDs to use in a `WHERE` clause. That list is too long for SQL Server and results in an error, so I am trying to cut the list into pieces to run smaller queries and loop through the pieces. My code works outside of `lapply`.

Because of the way that variables are called in `glue`, I'm seeing an error. I think `glue` is expecting a global variable rather than the list passed to it by the anonymous function as "x".

Here's a sample.

```
library(glue)
mylist <- list( `1` = c("1111","1112","1113","1114","1115"),
                `2` = c("2221","2222","2223","2224","2225"))

sqlcode <- lapply(mylist,
    function(x) glue_sql("
        SELECT *
        FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl]
        WHERE ID IN ({x*})
    "), .con = conn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me when I put the `.con=conn` inside the anon-func:

```r
sqlcode <- lapply(mylist,
#     function(x) glue::glue_sql("
#         SELECT *
#         FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl]
#         WHERE ID IN ({x*})
#     ", .con = conn))

sqlcode
# $`1`
# <SQL>     SELECT *
#     FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl]
#     WHERE ID IN ('1111', '1112', '1113', '1114', '1115')
# $`2`
# <SQL>     SELECT *
#     FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl]
#     WHERE ID IN ('2221', '2222', '2223', '2224', '2225')
```

An alternative to your effort, though, that requires only one query:

```r
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn, data.frame(id = unlist(mylist), "#sometemp")

### one of:
dat <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn,
  "select *
   from [db].[dbo].[tbl]
   where ID in (select * from #sometemp)")
### or
dat <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn,
  "select v.*
   from #sometemp t
     inner join [db].[dbo].[tbl] v on t.id=v.Id")

# not strictly necessary since it's a temporary table, but cleanup anyway
DBI::dbExecute(conn, "drop table #sometemp")
```

Note: the use of `"#"` to denote a temporary table is specific to SQL Server. Other DBMSes would instead use

```r
dbWriteTable(conn, data.frame(..), "sometemp", temporary=TRUE)
```

for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, I abandoned `glue` and went down the second path.